# How to delete a row containing a foreign key referencing multiple rows (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a `table_f`:

```
id_f | fk_1  | fk_2  | column_F
-------------------------------
1    | 1     | 1     | AA
2    | 1     | 2     | BB
3    | 1     | 2     | CC  <-- "Duplicate" of row id_f=2
4    | 2     | 1     | DD
```

And a `table_a`:

```
id_a  | fk_1 | fk_2
---------------------
1     | 1    | 1
2     | 1    | 2
3     | 2    | 1
```

`table_a` has a foreign key as: `[table_f.fk_1, table_f.fk_2]`, so I ensure that there is, at least, one record in `table_f`.

The problem is, I want to `delete from table_f where id_f=3`. But I cannot, because of the foreign key.

How can I ensure that a table has at least one row on another table, but being able to delete this row later?

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DELETE FROM table_f WHERE id_f = 3; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

Comment: I imagined that. But isn't it a bit unsafe?

Comment: Yep. Is real unsafe. So use this solution carefully

Comment: Post the create statements of the 2 tables to clarify which table references the other.